# Stack trace complaining about old non-existent codes

Tags: stack-trace

I have changed a piece of code completely from scratch re-using the same class. Changes were making a free-entry date field to a date entry, only with a calendar picker. It works on all systems, except one where it throws a stack trace complaining there are no getter methods for startDate in the class which was changed. It has been verified that all changes were merged and exist even on the system in which it doesn't work on. What could be the problem? What should I look into? I am completely lost on this one and any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like you may have got the new version of the class itself on the system, but not replaced the code that was *using* that class. Look at the caller in the stack trace, and check what version *that* is.